# comparing 2 int lengths C++

Tags: c++, string, std

I am trying to compare to integer lengths in terms of their digit lengths, and padding out the smallest one with 0's so they are both the same size, ie:

```
6 and 1500
```

becomes

```
0006 and 1500
```

I cannot get *std::stoi* to work, to then check the length of each number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int schoolMethod(int a, int b, int base){

if(std::stoi(a)<std::stoi(b)){
  //do stuff  
  return 0;
  }
}


karatsuba.cpp: In function ‘int schoolMethod(int, int, int)’:
karatsuba.cpp:50: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

Comment: You know [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) turns strings into `int`, not the other way around, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::stoi missing in g++ 4.7.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743904/stdstoi-missing-in-g-4-7-2)

Comment: Might help as well: [How can I count the digits in an integer without a string cast?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554521/how-can-i-count-the-digits-in-an-integer-without-a-string-cast)

Answer (score 1):

stoi takes **Const String** as parameter, but here you are passing `int`to it.

Use `std::to_string` method to convert `int` into `string` and then compare their lengths.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert your ints to strings to compare length, the following is a guide on how to basically do this.

`std::to_string()` will convert your ints to strings so you can then compare them.

`string.length()` will then return the length of the string.

```
#include <string>

int schoolMethod(int a, int b, int base){
    std::string stringa = std::to_string(a); //convert to string
    std::string stringb = std::to_string(b); //convert to string
    if(stringa.length()<stringb.length()){ //compare string lengths
      //do stuff  
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get this error: error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: I think if you remove using `namespace std;` or remove `std::` it will fix, one or the other

Comment: by chance is this your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g
If you are using an older version of c++ you won't be able to use to_string